# How do I check if a program terminates?

Tags: algorithm, termination

Is there a general rule that can be used to determine this? E.g:

```
int i = 10;
while (i > 1 ) {
  if (i%2 == 0) i = i/2;
  else i = 3*i - 1;
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, that particular program _will_ run forever. Since `3i-1` is greater than `i` for all `i>0`, that will always increase the value. And the only way to get 0 from an `i/2` operation (for `i>0`) is to start with `i==1`. And if `i==1`, you won't _use_ the `i=i/2` line since `i` is odd. The collatz conjecture should start `while (i > 1)` rather than 0.

Comment: @paxdiablo Changed to `while (i > 1)`

Comment: `i%2` is 0 when `i` is even, 1 when `i` is odd, so the `i = i/2` line will execute only when `i` is odd. Also, Collatz is also known as the 3n *plus* 1 problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). There does not exist an algorithm capable of doing what you ask.

In particular, if there was such an algorithm, then the [collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture), related to the function in your question, would be trivial (or at least a lot easier).

Comment: Why did this get downvoted? Is it because I was a little off hand with my grammar? I do appreciate the move from 4787 to 4785 though. Round numbers are nice.

Comment: @UncleO. The title of the question is "How do I check if an algorithm terminates?". The first sentence in the question is "Is there a general rule that can be used to determine this?". This is the halting problem. Don't let the presence of _one_ specific example confuse you. Also note, that OP read my answer and then _selected_ it as answering the question.

Comment: Upvoted your answer, but don't think that getting the 'accepted answer' somehow makes your answers immune to critique. That's wrong on so many levels I don't know where to begin. An accepted answer can still be shitty, incorrect, misleading, etc etc even if it apparently helped person who asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

You may be referring to the stopping problem. In short, there is no general way to determine if a program will stop.  Check out [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Why did this get down-voted? Is it because it's similar to Aaron's answer? We put them up within a few seconds of each other! I'd like feedback...

Answer (score 1):

In general, "no". As everyone else have said, with your specific example, it can be proven not to terminate, as `i` is only ever smaller if `i` is even (or if `i` is non-positive and odd, but given the initial conditions, that will never happen). The smallest positive even number is 2, this will then turn to 1 for the next iteration, where it will then be turned into 2.

Interestingly, you're not checking the Collatz Conjecture, as you are iterating "halve if even, 3*n-1 if odd" and the Collatz Conjecture iterates "halve if even, 3*n+1 if odd". I can't find this sequence discussed with a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods for [termination analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Termination_analysis)
 that can prove whether a program will halt. This is not always possible in Turing-complete programming languages, but there are several [total functional programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_functional_programming) that are limited to provably-halting programs.