# How to write code that checks if a program will terminate?

Tags: c++

If I were to write a small program which **took another c++ program**, with no compiler or runtime errors, **as an input file in text**, **how would I check if it will ever end**?

My idea right now is to only take the main cpp file as input, and check for while loops, do-while loops, for loops, and assert statements.

I feel like there are many more cases and that this might be a little over the top of my head.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You mean, how could you solve the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)? You can't.

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but the same answer. [How do I check if a program terminates?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3796792/3920237)

Comment: This video and a few more in the same channel will help you understand the problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nsZsd5qtbo4&list=UU9-y-6csu5WGm29I7JiwpnA&index=12

Comment: Isn't there a very restricted set of programs that you can prove whether or not it halts? I read somewhere that restricting a program to a set limit of memory and no IO. You can prove whether it halts or not. By stepping through a single instruction at a time and maintain all previous states ( memory/registers ). If a state repeats it does not halt. I should really find where I read that from.

Comment: @Smith_61 Yes. The existence of the halting problem does not mean that we can't build useful analysis tools (prefast, Z3, PVS-Studio to name a few) or restricted languages.

Comment: You can't do this for an arbitrary program, but you can possibly come close enough for your purposes if you accept "I give up; I have no idea" or non-termination as a valid answer. Trying to do it is an interesting exercise that forces you to think long and hard about computation, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is known as the "halting problem", and has been proved to be impossible to solve.

Suppose you had a function `bool halts(string program)` which determines whether the program will halt. You could then write a program

```
if (halts(input)) {
    while (true);
}
```

which halts if and only if its input doesn't. So if the input is this program, then it will halt if and only if it doesn't, which is a logical contradiction.

Therefore, such a function can't exist.

Comment: +1 but please add a link somewhere else (e.g. CS.SX or some other website discussing this issue).

Comment: @einpoklum: Why? This is a Q&A site, not a link farm. Google "halting problem" if you want to read more.

Comment: To provide the OP with a wider context for the answer. It's not merely a logical trick you thought of.

Comment: @einpoklum: He told everyone the name of the problem and explained it quite well. Further research is the OP's responsibility.

Comment: @einpoklum It's not exactly obscure. Sure, the OP may not be aware of what the "halting problem" is, a google search for "check if program will terminate" has a top link for the wikipedia article.

Comment: Never mind, OP can read the other answer or these comments; anyway, it never hurts to be nicer to newbies...

Comment: @einpoklum: It has nothing to do with being "nice", nor whether someone is a "newbie" or not. How is someone supposed to become a not-newbie if they have everything spoon-fed to them all the time? This answer is great. I don't understand your concern.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: He'll become a not-newbie by learning - by reading up on certain subjects, by coding, by taking courses in Comp Sci (maybe), and by asking rudimentary easy-to-answer questions, or finding them using search. Linking to background information on Turing machines and the halting problem is likely to help him along. In my opinion. (Also, remember I upvoted MikeSeymour's even without the link.)

Comment: @einpoklum: Mike _did_ link to it. In the very first comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is known that this problem cannot ever be solved.
Mathematically, [it is impossible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).